# Using dojo dojox/dtl in AMD outside of a widget

Tags: dojo

I want to use dojo doxox/dtl in AMD, OUTSIDE OF A WIDGET!
Currently (2012-02-10) the documentation is not updated to dojo 1.7 AMD (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/dtl.html).
In the old documentation the non-AMD example is:

```
dojo.require("dojox.dtl");
dojo.require("dojox.dtl.Context");
var template = new dojox.dtl.Template("Hello {{ place }}!");
var context = new dojox.dtl.Context({ place: "World" });
console.debug(template.render(context)); // Hello World!
```

To produce the same output with the new Dojo 1.7 framework, my solution would be to subclass "dojox/dtl/_Templated" and in the constructor of the new class set the template value to the attribute "templateString".

My question is:

Can anybody help me doing dtl templates outside of a widget without subclassing "dojox/dtl/_Templated"?

Thanks alot in advance
Wolfgang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
define(["dojox/dtl/_base", "dojox/dtl/Context"], function (dtl, Context) {
  var compiledTemplate, templateObj, contextObj;
  templateObj = new dtl.Template ("Hello {{ place }}!");
  contextObj  = new Context({ place: "World" });
  compiledTemplate = templateObj.render(contextObj);        
...
```

Comment: You also want to include 'dojox/dtl/tag/logic' and add an alias to the list of function params in line 1.  You don't need to change the code below; just ensure that module is required.